# I would like to run a relay node on Ubuntu 20 server without creating a wallet, what are my options? Are packaged binaries available?

Tags: node

I am looking to setup a full node on an Ubuntu 20.04 server for mainnet and leave it running. I don't intend to run a stakepool. Are there any packaged distributions I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stake pool is just a full node with some additional configuration, so the binaries are the same.

If you need to run `cardano-node`, you might want to start with its [Getting started documentation](https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-node/en/latest/) and you can find the release binaries on the [Github's release page](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases) of `cardano-node`.